# Некорректное отображение HTML письма на iOS

Tags: html, css

Здравствуйте. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть косяк. Сверстал письмо HTML. Везде хорошо отображается, но в стандартном приложении iOS отображается оно на пол экрана. Что я не так делаю? Прикладываю скрин с iOS
[image: iOS]

**Код письма:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>Ваш заказ</title>
</head>
<div style="letter-spacing: 596px; line-height: 0; mso-hide: all">&nbsp;</div>
<!-- nbsp is 4px wide -->

<body style="margin:0; font-family:Arial;">
  <div id="mailsub">
    <table width="530" style="margin: 0 auto;color:#2d2721;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="3" style="height:65px"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td style="text-align:center">
            <a href="#">
              <img style="width:120px;" src="http://verstka.test30.ru/letters/food-let1/logo.png" alt="FoodMarket">
            </a>
          </td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="3" style="height:55px"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="3" style="color:#548000;font-size:16px;font-weight:bold">[ИМЯ], Спасибо за ваш заказ</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="3" style="height:15px"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="3" style="font-size:15px;font-weight:500">курьер свяжется с вами за 2 часа до доставки</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="3" style="height:28px"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="3" style="color:#548000;font-size:16px;font-weight:bold">Заказ №12020</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="3" style="height:15px"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="3" style="font-size:15px;font-weight:500">дата доставки: 25 апреля 2017 г.</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="3" style="height:15px"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="3" style="font-size:15px;font-weight:500">время доставки: с 9:00 до 13:00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="3" style="height:15px"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="3" style="font-size:15px;font-weight:500">адрес доставки: ул. Бакинская 79</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="3" style="height:15px"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="3" style="font-size:15px;font-weight:500">
            <span style="display:block;border-top:1px solid #ccc;width:530px;margin-left:1px;"></span>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="3" style="height:15px"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td>
            <table style="width:530px;border-collapse:collapse">
              <tr>
                <td>Сушеный укроп</td>
                <td>1 кг</td>
                <td style="width:150px;text-align:right">4 650 р</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td colspan="3" style="height:15px"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Сушеный укроп</td>
                <td>1 кг</td>
                <td style="width:150px;text-align:right">4 650 р</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td colspan="3" style="height:15px"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Сушеный укроп</td>
                <td>1 кг</td>
                <td style="width:150px;text-align:right">4 650 р</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td colspan="3" style="height:15px"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Сушеный укроп</td>
                <td>1 кг</td>
                <td style="width:150px;text-align:right">4 650 р</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td colspan="3" style="height:15px"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Сушеный укроп</td>
                <td>1 кг</td>
                <td style="width:150px;text-align:right">4 650 р</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td colspan="3" style="height:15px"></td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="3" style="height:15px"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="3" style="color:#548000;font-size:16px;font-weight:bold">стоимость доставки</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="3" style="height:15px"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="3" style="font-size:15px;font-weight:500">0 р</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="3" style="height:28px"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="3" style="color:#548000;font-size:16px;font-weight:bold">итоговая стоимость</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="3" style="height:15px"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="3" style="font-size:15px;font-weight:500">23 222 р</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="3" style="height:90px"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td>
            <table style="width:530px;border-collapse:collapse">
              <tr>
                <td style="width:138px"></td>
                <td style="width:38px">
                  <a href="#">
                    <img style="width:38px" src="http://verstka.test30.ru/letters/food-let1/social1.png" alt="social">
                  </a>
                </td>
                <td style="width:38px"></td>
                <td style="width:38px">
                  <a href="#">
                    <img style="width:38px" src="http://verstka.test30.ru/letters/food-let1/social2.png" alt="facebook">
                  </a>
                </td>
                <td style="width:38px"></td>
                <td style="width:38px">
                  <a href="#">
                    <img style="width:38px" src="http://verstka.test30.ru/letters/food-let1/social2.png" alt="instagramm">
                  </a>
                </td>
                <td style="width:38px"></td>
                <td style="width:38px">
                  <a href="#">
                    <img style="width:38px" src="http://verstka.test30.ru/letters/food-let1/social2.png" alt="whats app">
                  </a>
                </td>
                <td style="width:138px"></td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: [Ссылка на код](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xgYKWZ)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Разобрался с проблемой вставкой тега `<meta name=”x-apple-disable-message-reformatting”>`

Вся проблема в Apple Mail в iOS 10. Если кому интересно, можете [тут](https://litmus.com/blog/9-things-you-need-to-know-about-email-in-ios-10) почитать пункт 3

Comment: Ответ уже должно быть можно принимать.

Answer (score 1):

Предположу, что дело в отсутствии

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Comment: К сожалению, не помогло